# In python logging, is it accepted practice to setLevel() in a library to establish a default?

Tags: python, logging, log4j

wrt the python standard logging framework,
is there an accepted wisdom in the Python world (or even in the log4j world) about doing setLevel() inside a library module that you're authoring?
Doing a setLevel() inside your library lets you establish a default,
and yet that default is easy to override by the sw that's using the library module.

Is this accepted as good practice or considered bad practice?

```
    """library module"""
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Is this accepted as good practice or considered bad practice?
    ...
    logger.info('milepost')
```

Maybe (A), "Yes, do it!"  The practice is widespread -- see for yourself by cd-ing to your python tree, and see

```
egrep -r setLevel --exclude-dir=test --exclude-dir=tests *
```

Or (B), "No, it's bad form!"  There already exists a "default"... implicit from a logger's ancestor in the hierarchy of loggers.
If you make yet another default, it's confusing to the users of your library.
Also, what if configurating (from a json or yaml-file, in the main code) happens before your library is loaded?  Then later, your library is imported for the first time (loaded).  Maybe a library default could override what was already configured via the configuration-file.  That would be confusing too!

Or (C), "Yes, explicit is better than implicit!"

I'm hoping this has a clear answer, but I haven't found it yet.
Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 2):

I am reading this below as implying DON'T setLevel() in the library you're authoring.  Let it be, because the framework already defaults to WARNING, right?
From https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library,

> Configuring Logging for a Library
> When developing a library which uses
> logging, you should take care to document how the library uses logging
> -- for example, the names of loggers used. Some consideration also needs to be given to its logging configuration. If the using
> application does not use logging, and library code makes logging
> calls, then (as described in the previous section) events of severity
> WARNING and greater will be printed to sys.stderr. This is regarded as
> the best default behaviour.